# Caching response with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, caching, swift3, alamofire

I develop an iOS application. I use Alamofire to call my api and get datas.
I create an extension of Alamofire in order to define cache policy.

```
extension Alamofire.SessionManager{

    @discardableResult
    open func requestWithCacheOrLoad(
        _ url: URLConvertible,
        method: HTTPMethod = .get,
        parameters: Parameters? = nil,
        encoding: ParameterEncoding = URLEncoding.default,
        headers: HTTPHeaders? = nil)
        -> DataRequest
    {
        do {
            var urlRequest = try URLRequest(url: url, method: method, headers: headers)
            urlRequest.cachePolicy = .returnCacheDataElseLoad
            let encodedURLRequest = try encoding.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
            return request(encodedURLRequest)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return request(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://example.com/wrong_request")!))
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine but I have a problem.

In my ViewControllers before each request that I send I create an AlertView to show the user that the request is processing. And when my request has a http status code 200, I dismiss this AlertView.

So when the response is not cached it's helpful but when the response is cached it's useless so I search a way to not display this AlertView.

```
func getCities(){
    self.showLoadingModal() // <- Show alert view
    let parameters: Parameters = [
        "token": UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token")!,
        ]

    Alamofire.SessionManager.default.requestWithCacheOrLoad(Constant.api_base_url+"cities", method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<APIResponse>) in

        let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
        if(statusCode == 200){
            if((response.result.value?.popup?.count)! > 0){
                self.popupSwiftMessage(reward: (response.result.value?.popup?[0])!)
            }

            self.cities = response.result.value?.responseCities
            self.cities_table_view.reloadData()
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // <- Dismiss alert view
        } else{
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.errorSwiftMessage(message: "Une erreur est survenue, veuillez réessayer ultérieurement.")
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you